# Transform texts field to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file where each line contain information like:

```
a: send value b: XYZ
```

How can I transform this to have a dictionary for each line:

```
{'a': 'send value', 'b': 'XYZ'}
```

What I have done before but I have some problems with text :

```
from parse import parse
import sys
with open("txt.txt") as fi:
    line = fi.readline()
    result = list(parse('{}: {} {}: {}', line))
    print({i:j for i,j in zip(result[::2], result[1::2])})
```

AND my result is :
    `{'a': 'send', 'value b': 'XYZ'}`

What is the the best way to handle text content

Comment: Are you sure the key will not contain white space?

Comment: Can you use CSV files or does it have to be a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use regex to accomplish this:

```
import re

# Assuming your keywords will not contain any white space...
# The captive group ensure the keyword is returned with re.split
pat = re.compile(r'(\S+): ')

with open('txt.txt', 'r') as file:
  for line in file.readlines():

    # Split all the pairs and remove any empty elements
    pairs = [t for t in pat.split(line.strip()) if t]

    # Create a dictionary based on keys from even indices, and vals from odd indices.
    result = {k: v for k, v in zip(pairs[::2], pairs[1::2])}
    print(result)
```

[Sample code](https://repl.it/repls/GruesomeNocturnalDimension)

Given `txt.txt`:

```
a: send value b: XYZ
c12: some other thing d_56e: qrst uvw xy f83!$#&*: foobar
```

Results would be:

```
{'a': 'send value ', 'b': 'XYZ'}
{'c12': 'some other thing ', 'd_56e': 'qrst uvw xy ', 'f83!$#&*': 'foobar'}
```

The key part to this solution is to identify a consistent pattern of how the key/vals are split and update `pat` accordingly.  For instance, there are multiple whitespaces after `:` you  might want to use pattern `r'(\S+):\s+'` instead.

Here's a relevant sample for the regex pattern as well: https://regex101.com/r/jyMWQ1/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to capture all couples of `key: value` pairs using capture groups. Then, using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.findall) the result will be a list of tuples of the form `(key, value)` for each match. This then can be handed directly to the dict constructor.

A possible regex that you can modify to your needs is:

```
(\w+): (.*?)(?= \w+:|$)
```

Then it can be used as:

```py
import re

lines = ["a: send value b: XYZ", 
         "a: send b: ABC XYZ"]

pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+): (.*?)(?= \w+:|$)")
for line in lines:
    print(dict(pattern.findall(line)))
```

And this will print out:

```
{'a': 'send value', 'b': 'XYZ'}
{'a': 'send', 'b': 'ABC XYZ'}
```

---

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zkwaey/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
text_split="a: send value b: XYZ c: hello world".split(' ')
keys=[[x,idx] for idx,x in enumerate(text_split) if ":" in x]+[[None,None]]
values=[" ".join(text_split[keys[idx][1]+1:keys[idx+1][1]]) for idx in range(len(keys)-1)]
dictionary=dict(zip([x.replace(":","") for x,y in keys[:-1]],values))
print(dictionary)
# or maybe this both work you can choose either one
text_split="a: send value b: XYZ c: hello world".split(':')
dictionary={x.split(' ')[-1]:" ".join([y for y in text_split[idx+1].split(' ')[1:-1 if idx+2!=len(text_split) else None]]) for idx,x in enumerate(text_split) if idx+1!=len(text_split)}
print(dictionary)
```

your output:

```
{'a': 'send value', 'b': 'XYZ', 'c': 'hello world'}
```